# Change one precise mat-tab background color- Angular Material

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material, mat-tab

I want to change ONE precise mat-tab background color, there is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54435122/how-to-change-background-color-of-specific-angular-material-tabs) solution which works but is a bit more complexe than needed.

I have this current code which work but I want to remove the first button with aria-label id

**HTML :**

```
<div>
  <mat-button-toggle-group #backgroundColorToggle="matButtonToggleGroup" value="custom">
    <mat-button-toggle value="custom"> custom </mat-button-toggle>
  </mat-button-toggle-group>
</div>

<mat-tab-group>
  <mat-tab label="First" [aria-label]=backgroundColorToggle.value> Content 1 </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Second"> Content 2 </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

**CSS :**

```
[aria-label=custom] {
  background-color: #5473a1;
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

I'd like to have something more simple like that but it's not working :

```
<mat-tab-group>
  <mat-tab label="First" [aria-label]="custom"> Content 1 </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Second"> Content 2 </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

Thx !

Comment: You can add precise CSS.

Comment: I did not find any way to select a precise mat-tab, I can't add class in it (or I don't know how, class="" do not work) 
I can change text color with ng-template and add a span in my tab but can't select the tab itself

Comment: Did you try with `id` and then stylize it with `CSS`? 
Can you provide a `stackblitz`?

Comment: Nope, material generate new element si classes and ids are lost ... But I found a solution, I will upload it tomorrow ! Thx tho

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution I find :

```
.mat-tab-label-content {
    .my-tab-color {
        &.my-tab-color-green {
            background-color: $mygreen;
            color: white;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should target the first tab ( body ).

```
.mat-tab-group .mat-tab-body:first-child .mat-tab-body-content{background: red;}
```